# How can I know which tasks are running in the background?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibackgroundtask

I'm trying to implement a seemingly common feature in my app: to upload files in the background. I run such tasks by calling `-[UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:]`, so those tasks are each identified by a `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier`.

Please take a look at the diagram below. Orange boxes are problem points for which I can't seem to find any answer.

[image]

Here are the questions for which I seek guidance:

Is it possible to get a list of running tasks that same app initiated in a previous session?

Is it possible to associate some kind of meta data, such as a URL string, with a background task, so we can know which task is uploading which file?

Comment: As written, your question is too vague. Are you talking about running on a background thread, using NSThread, NSOperations, or GCD queues? Or are you talking about asking for background time when the user swaps your app to the background?

Comment: I want the OS to continue uploading the files, even when the app is closed or sent to background.

Comment: See Rob's answer. You want NSURLSession. It lets you handle uploads/downloads even when your app is in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLSession`?

If `NSURLSession`, you can use `getTasksWithCompletionHandler`. You can also use a background `NSURLSessionConfiguration`, rather than relying on `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`. And it terms of keeping track of the requests, you can retrieve the `originalRequest` from the task (and retrieve the URL from that), or update your model with the `taskIdentifier` for the `NSURLSessionTask`, and cross reference requests in your own model that way.